# deep learning and model performance

Tags: amazon-web-services, deep-learning

I was making load tests on a model that classifies nsfw images.

aws c5.large instance (2vCPU, 4 gm mem) using caffe-cpu : processing an image takes about 700ms

aws p3.2xlarge specialized deep learning GPU instance with a Tesla V100 GPU, (16gb gpu mem, 8 vCPU, 61gb mem), using caffe-gpu with cuda, cudnn, and all that stuff - and it processes the image in about 950ms.

I expected the processing time to be much faster. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: What software are you using for the classification? Is it configured to use a GPU?

Comment: @EricJ. yes, looks like it. I hope. But should it be faster on GPU? Perhaps some configurations were incorrect. What do you think?